# Azure Application Insights | KQL | Get exception details

Tags: azure, exception, azure-application-insights, kql, azure-monitoring

We are using Azure application Insights for error logging. I am new to KQL and trying to fetch custom properties from inbuilt "customDimensions" column in the following format,

**Data in "customDimensions" column**

```
{
  "File Name":"Sample File 1",
  "Correlation ID":"e33a8d45-0566-4bf2-94f8-54a6fec29bff",
  "Error List":"[
      {
        "Function Name":"Sample Function 1",
        "Code":"#231256#"
      },
      {
        "Function Name":"Sample-Function-2",
        "Code":"#231258#"
      },
   ]"
}
```

**Expected Output**

| File Name | Correlation ID | Function Name | Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sample File 1 | e33a8d45-0566-4bf2-94f8-54a6fec29bff | Sample Function 1 | #231256# |
| Sample File 1 | e33a8d45-0566-4bf2-94f8-54a6fec29bff | Sample-Function-2 | #231258# |

How can I achieve the above output using KQL?

Thank You.

Update: Adding a sample datatable

```
datatable(ErrorDetails:dynamic)
[
    dynamic({
        "File Name":"Sample File 1",
        "Correlation ID":"e33a8d45-0566-4bf2-94f8-54a6fec29bff",
        "Error List": [{
                "Function Name":"Sample Function 1",
                "Code":"#231256#"
            },
            {
                "Function Name":"Sample-Function-2",
                "Code":"#231258#"
            }
        ]
    })
]
```

Comment: This input does not make sense. Please copy the value As Is, preferably as a datatable

Comment: Updated datatable in the question

Comment: Sure David. Here is my related post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72436650/azure-application-insights-kql-customdimensions-column-containing-array-of-o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mv-expand](https://mv-expand) operator

```
datatable(ErrorDetails:dynamic)
[
    dynamic({
        "File Name":"Sample File 1",
        "Correlation ID":"e33a8d45-0566-4bf2-94f8-54a6fec29bff",
        "Error List": [{
                "Function Name":"Sample Function 1",
                "Code":"#231256#"
            },
            {
                "Function Name":"Sample-Function-2",
                "Code":"#231258#"
            }
        ]
    })
]
| mv-expand EL = ErrorDetails.["Error List"]
| project ["File Name"] = ErrorDetails["File Name"], ["Correlation ID"] = ErrorDetails["Correlation ID"], ["Function Name"] = EL["Function Name"], ["Code"] = EL["Code"]
```

| File Name | Correlation ID | Function Name | Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sample File 1 | e33a8d45-0566-4bf2-94f8-54a6fec29bff | Sample Function 1 | #231256# |
| Sample File 1 | e33a8d45-0566-4bf2-94f8-54a6fec29bff | Sample-Function-2 | #231258# |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA41Ry2rDMBC8+ysW5ZJAVBr5gWPIKUmhYHrp0fggWxKo+IWilpY2/15ZaWpZObSri2Z3ZnekZVSbUzV8eVSqVweuqWxOGfvoaCvrVVAEYOIHLj8tGgM9yIbDE205ytAzbQeDbGqD1hNp3yvFG6pl38HjwTB5GNKURTG+j5MER5UgeBuJFMcRTQSvybYSwm1gTUEuTxplUEzjJxuvXW3be1auadeOY4uN3AUJNyROFmjGOM8F/56Jr2lM/pyZ+jN/UWlv51VQBl/QvmH+PtCOwTGHHbgbuivcvxnJg+pfeK2hcFZTeqpZbW2o3oJu+T5hFM3fbzX5TfbSnU31C/gGtMZ3CXACAAA=)

Comment: Thank you, David. It works fine with datatable but it doesn't work with customDimensions column. I have updated the question with more details and value as is.

Comment: Please refer - Update 2

Answer (score 0):

> How can I achieve the above output using KQL?

- *Beow is the sample command which can be used to get the **correlation id** and **function names** in column.*

```
customEvents
 | extend Org = tostring(customDimensions.correlationID)
```

- *Refer this [**document**](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ac7fc210-a3f3-4e12-b8c0-a0ffa5982ffd/showing-custom-dimension-values-into-columns-kql?forum=ApplicationInsights) which has related discussion.*

Comment: I'm able to extend individual values but unable to handle array of objects. Please refer my expected output.