# Azure Application Insights | KQL | customDimensions column containing array of objects

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, kql, azure-monitoring, kusto-explorer

We are using Azure application Insights for error logging. I am new to KQL and trying to fetch custom properties from inbuilt "customDimensions" column in the following format,

**Value as is from "customDimensions" column**

```
exceptions
| project customDimensions


{
"File Name":"Sample File 1",
"Correlation ID":"e33a8d45-1234-1234-1223-54a6fec30356",
"Error List":"[
{\"Function Name\":\"Sample Function 1\",\"Code\":\"12345\"},
{\"Function Name\":\"Sample-Function-2\",\"Code\":\"12343\"}]"
}
```

**Expected Output**

| File Name | Correlation ID | Function Name | Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sample File 1 | e33a8d45-1234-1234-1223-54a6fec30356 | Sample Function 1 | 12345 |
| Sample File 1 | e33a8d45-1234-1234-1223-54a6fec30356 | Sample-Function-2 | 12343 |

How can I achieve the above output using KQL?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might seem a little bit tricky, but bear with me :-)

- Every sub-element extracted from a dynamic element, is dynamic.
- [parse_json() / todynamic()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parsejsonfunction) when given a dynamic argument, returns it, As Is.
  So first, we use [tostring()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/tostringfunction) and only then we use todynamic() so the string would be parsed as json, to dynamic type.

---

```
datatable(ErrorDetails:dynamic)
[
    dynamic({
        "File Name":"Sample File 1",
        "Correlation ID":"e33a8d45-0566-4bf2-94f8-54a6fec29bff",
        "Error List":"[{\"Function Name\":\"Sample Function 1\",\"Code\":\"12345\"},{\"Function Name\":\"Sample-Function-2\",\"Code\":\"12343\"}]"
    })
]
| mv-expand EL = todynamic(tostring(ErrorDetails["Error List"]))
| project ["File Name"] = ErrorDetails["File Name"], ["Correlation ID"] = ErrorDetails["Correlation ID"], ["Function Name"] = EL["Function Name"], ["Code"] = EL["Code"]
```

| File Name | Correlation ID | Function Name | Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sample File 1 | e33a8d45-0566-4bf2-94f8-54a6fec29bff | Sample Function 1 | 12345 |
| Sample File 1 | e33a8d45-0566-4bf2-94f8-54a6fec29bff | Sample-Function-2 | 12343 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA31QS2uEMBC%20C/6HkNMKBuqTXaGn7i4UpJcejYdokpKiRmJaWrb73xtNbXWFJqeZ7zEzHyXa/Kphu5NSUh2ZJqIZMvrZkVbUnusUrgPM%202nsLrYcHzyLhoEn0jKYwWfS9qaaWgH0F6wHqRRriBayA49HQ2VRRPY0TtBdkqYorniIDjHfoyQmKWd1eKg4XzlMm4FcDNqoiwuG57eunvzG4Rhm%20Hf8DAQY%20tiMphYOwihOMLz6/4jRDKBwK46MuIR2p6tJpXSdL9C%20I/bRk46CUw7ugZZzSFoOWonuZZVpsbyj9LzRoVfyldUaFIssS2O11i0w31BvAt3ybwmjaHW11eSbrnWnf7gtvgHP7T8dJAIAAA==)